# PHP Session - not saving

Tags: php, session, header

I'm working on an admin page for my site, but I found a problem. My code worked perfectly with Wamp (and still working in Chrome, but not for other people, or in other browsers).
So, the problem is that my site don't save the session variable after header redirecting. (Another thing I can't figure out is, that if I put the die or exit after the header the page just go blank, and you must refresh manually. Still it's only on the webserver.)

```
<?php
session_start();
$log = $_GET['logout'];
$error = false;
//logout
if($log==true){
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    //die;
}
//login
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !isset($_SESSION['user']) ){
    $file="login.xml";
    $xml=simplexml_load_file($file) or die ("Unable to load XMl file!");
    $nope=true;
    $givenuser = $_POST['username'];
    $givenpass = md5($_POST['password']);
    foreach($xml->user as $user){
        $username = $user->username;
        $password = $user->password;
        if ($givenuser == $username && $givenpass == $password){
            $_SESSION['user'] = $givenuser;
            $nope =false;
            header('Location: '. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            //die();
        }
    }
    if($nope) $error = true;
}
//succesful login
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    ?>
    <html>
    <header><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" /></header>
    <body>
    <h1>
    <?php echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['user']; ?>
    </h1>
    <div> 
        <a href="?">New page</a> 
        <a href="?logout=true">Logout</a>
    </div>
    <div id="menus">
        Pages:</br>
        <?php
            $file="../pages.xml";
            $xml=simplexml_load_file($file) or die ("Unable to load XMl file!");
            $index = 0;
            foreach($xml->xpath('//oldalneve') as $pagename){
                echo '<a href="?id='.$index.'">'.$pagename.'</a></br>';
                $index=$index+1;
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
        if(!is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
            $id=-1;
        }else{
            $id=(int)$_GET['id'];
        }
        if($id!=-1){
            $id=(int)$_GET['id'];
            if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['body'])){
                if($_REQUEST['name'] !="" && $_REQUEST['body']!=""){
                    $file="../pages.xml";
                    $xml= simplexml_load_file($file) or die ("Unable to load XML file!");
                    $name = $_POST['name'];
                    $body = $_POST['body'];
                    $xml->page[$id]->oldalneve = $name;
                    $xml->page[$id]->body = $body;
                    $xml->asXML('../pages.xml');
                    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?id='.$id);
                    //die;
                    }
            }
            $file="../pages.xml";
            $xml= simplexml_load_file($file);
            $nam=$xml->page[$id]->oldalneve;
            $val=$xml->page[$id]->body;
            ?>
            <div style="float:left;">
                <form name="input" method="post" action="" >
                    <label>Name</label></br>
                    <input type="text" name="name" style="width:250px" value="<?php echo $nam;?>"></br>
                    <label>Body</label></br>
                    <textarea cols="28" rows="10" name="body"><?php echo $val;?></textarea></br>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Küldés">
                </form>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
            <?php
        }else{ 
    ?>
            <div style="float:left;">
                <form name="input" method="post" action="" >
                    <fieldset><legend>Add page</legend>
                        <label>Name</label></br>
                        <input type="text" name="name" style="width:250px"></br>
                        <label>Body</label></br>
                        <textarea cols="28" rows="10"v name="body"></textarea></br>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Küldés">
                    </fieldset> 
                </form>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                if($_REQUEST['name'] !="" && $_REQUEST['body']!=""){
                    $file="../pages.xml";
                    $xml= simplexml_load_file($file) or die ("Unable to load XML file!");
                    $page=$xml->addChild('page');
                    $name = $_POST['name'];
                    $body = $_POST['body'];
                    $page->addChild('oldalneve', $name);
                    $page->addChild('body', $body);

                    $xml->asXML('../pages.xml');
                    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                    //die;
                }
            }
        }
}else
{
    showLogin($error);
}
function showLogin($error){?>

    <form action="" method='post'>
        <label for="username">username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username"></br>
        <label for="password">password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"></br>
        <?php
            if($error){
            echo "Invalid username or password".'</br>';
            }
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form> 

<?php }

?>
```

The user can login and see the interface, but using one of the links will redirect him to the login screen (Session user is not saved).

Here is the phpinfo():

```
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   On  On
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 4   4
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /tmp    /tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Comment: I think you have a problem with this condition : if($log==true). If you try with "===" what happens ?

Comment: This smells like a *Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by* kind of problem. Do you have any PHP errors/warnings? (use `ini_set("display_errors", true)` if they are suppressed, or check the source code because they might be printed before `<html>` and thus not visible on the page)

Comment: Chafik: with === logout doesn't work at all.
solymosi: actually I do get that error. I modified the code so every printed code gets in the <html> tag.
If I activate the die; codes I still get the error and nothing shows up.

Comment: Are your source files encoded in UTF-8? If they are, they might have a BOM which gets printed before anything else. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034750/can-saving-in-unicode-utf-8-including-bom-elements-break-my-header-location-on-m

Comment: To remove the BOM *(byte-order mark)*, change the settings of your editor so that it does not include a BOM and save *all* related files again (Notepad++ example: Encoding menu > Convert to UTF-8 without BOM).

Comment: The encoding was okay. I did 
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>....
<?php
$log = $_GET['logout'];
And that caused the error again, but I changed it to an echo '<html>..' so it's working now! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Chafik is partly right.

```
if($_GET['logout'] == true)
```

is a bad way to do this (a lot of thing would make that statement true). But he's incorrect in that `===` would solve it. Even if you set `?logout=true`, `$_GET['logout']` would contain the **string** `true`, not a boolean value so your `===` would wind up `false` (`"true"` !== `true`). I would use

```
if(isset($_GET['logout']))
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the Reason could be

1. to include session_start(); on the top of every page to get the values of variable SET in the SESSION through $_SESSION['example'], otherwise You will not be able to the session Variable values ,

   2.A different Approach is to use session_start(); inside config.php file and include that file on the top of the code of every page where sessions are required otherwise U will not be able to get the value of SESSION variable..!!